# Docker compose volume overrides COPY in multi-stage build

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

My goal is to get php dependencies in one stage of a docker file then copy those dependencies to the next stage (the `vendor/` dir). However, once a volume is specified in `docker-compose.yml` that overrides the `COPY` statement as if it never happened.

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
```

**`docker/app/Dockerfile`**

```docker
FROM composer AS php_builder
COPY . /app
RUN composer install --no-dev

FROM php:7.1-fpm
COPY --from=php_builder /app/vendor /var/www/html/vendor
```

The result of building and running this is a `/var/www/html` directory that doesn't have the `vendor/` directory as I'd expect.

My guess is that this is because the volume specified in the `docker-compose.yml` service definition actually happens *after* the `COPY --from` statement which seems to be logical. But how do I get around this? I'd still like to use a volume here instead of an `ADD` or `COPY` command.

Comment: The only option is to put the vendor folder somewhere else as the volume will always override it. It shouldn't be in the docroot anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can combine `bind mounts` & `volume` to make your aim, a minimal example for your reference:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - my_folder:/var/www/html/vendor
      - .:/var/www/html

volumes:
  my_folder:
```

**docker/app/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM composer AS php_builder
COPY . /app
#RUN composer install --no-dev
RUN mkdir -p vendor && echo "I'm dependency!" > vendor/dependencies.txt

FROM php:7.1-fpm
COPY --from=php_builder /app/vendor /var/www/html/vendor
```

**Results:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/test$ ls
docker  docker-compose.yaml  index.php
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/test$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "test_default" with the default driver
Creating test_app_1 ... done
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/test$ docker exec -it test_app_1 /bin/bash
root@bf59d8684581:/var/www/html# ls
docker  docker-compose.yaml  index.php  vendor
root@bf59d8684581:/var/www/html# cat vendor/dependencies.txt
I'm dependency!
```

From above execution, you can see the `dependencies.txt` which generated in the first stage of `Dockerfile` still could be seen in the container, [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) just manage the data by docker itself, while [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) give you chance to manage data for yourself.